# Question related to hover and setInterval

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I use the hover function and on mouseover a setInterval function begins working
and onmouseout i clear the setInterval function

My code is as follows:

**----UPDATED----**
For the slideShow i have a div name divForImages and i .append() the new image in that specific div. I use the .append() function.
My algorithm is really simple:
FadeOut the previous image and .append() the new image by using the Fadein function.
So the new updated version is:

```
var IntervalID;    

$("li").hover(
            function() {                                                        
                    IntervalID = setInterval(function() {
                                    //a slideshow begins to auto play...

                        $(".divForImages img").fadeOut(1000); //previous image

                        var item = $('<img src="'+attribute_of_href+'"   width="200" height="100" style="left:0px;top:0px;position:absolute"  />').css({"display":"none"}); //new image that is going to be faded in
                       $(".divForImages").append(item);/* new */

                       item.fadeIn(1000);
                                    }, 4000);
                       },
            function() {                
                    clearInterval(IntervalID);
                        });
```

The milliseconds i have defined are 4000.
The problem is that when i **FIRST** mousover the li, the slideshow doesn't begin 
to autoplay immediately but it waits for 4 seconds!

Of course, i have defined the time for 4000 seconds

Can i make the setInterval to start **immediately** when i mouseover and not wait for 4000 ms??

thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function playSlideShow() {
    //a slideshow begins to auto play...
}

$("li").hover(
    function() {    
            playSlideShow();    // start playing immediately        
            IntervalID = setInterval(playSlideShow, 4000);
    },
    function() {                
            clearInterval(IntervalID);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [settimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead of [setinterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

to learn more check [setinterval vs settimeout](http://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enEG430EG430&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#pq=setinterval&hl=en&cp=13&gs_id=8&xhr=t&q=setInterval%20vs%20settimeout&qe=c2V0SW50ZXJ2YWwgdg&qesig=cYjk-eyRxLsT0FrkdqCJ9Q&pkc=AFgZ2tlwniESvLdL5qNTIexkHat4NfzK75vzzCA4aCL7GDWl7qCMnFkkRAS2XiwPXwh8bjlHlRButgtuT140JidDz9d7h7wR6g&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enEG430EG430&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=setInterval%20v&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=e201e109e10c6471&biw=1680&bih=882&ion=1)

Comment: This will still cause it to wait `4000ms` before it fires, but then it will only fire once. OP want's an interval for a slideshow.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but settimeout fires only once, and i need the setInterval function for the autoplay of the images

Comment: patrick dw you are correct about that, so i see that @Mrchief is good, in both case if he used setinterval or setimeout

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just name the function, invoked it immediately, and have it return itself by name to the `setInterval()`.

```
var IntervalID;
var slideshow = function () {
        //a slideshow begins to auto play...
    return slideshow; // <-- the return value lets you invoke and pass it.
};

$("li").hover( function () {
    IntervalID = setInterval( slideshow(), 4000);
}, function () {
    clearInterval(IntervalID);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Hgwt8/

Comment: Thanks for the coding, it actually worked!But i have a slight problem,it's too fast!Imagine that i have a slideshow and when i first mouseover i miss the first image cause it iterates to the second one immediately.Do you think that i shall use in this case settimeout as @Amr_ElGarhy says in order to postpone that a bit?can this be done??

Comment: @programmer: There must be some other issue with your code, perhaps with a starting index number. You'll need to post actual code to be sure.

Comment: Well maybe you are right, cause i use fadeIn and fadeOut in the slide show and i do:

Comment: Yes, i use fadeIn and fadeOut with 1000ms, does it matter??Also,I added new code in the my first post